# jQuery tabs change tab after .preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to stop default behaviour on a tab change based on certain conditions. My problem is that once I have issued a `.preventDefault()` on my tabs I cannot change to the tab that the user wanted to go to before the `.beforeActivate` event. I am using the jQuery messagebox plugin which cannot pause the code until user confirms.

```
<script>
$("#tabs").tabs({});
</script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ajax/divs/tabbed/tripinfo.php?id=<?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]; ?>">Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/divs/tabbed/tripinfo_expenses.php?id=<?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]; ?>">Expenses</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/divs/tabbed/tripinfo_fuel.php?id=<?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]; ?>">Fuel Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/divs/tabbed/equipment_info.php?id=<?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]; ?>">Equipment</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/divs/tabbed/tripinfo_route.php?id=<?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]; ?>">Route Configuration</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
var rows = $("#numbered tbody tr").not(":last").length;
$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        // If user exits without saving alert
        if (rows != $("#numbered tbody tr").not(":last").length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.confirm('YOU HAVE MADE CHANGES TO THIS ROUTE. ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO LEAVE THE PAGE? ALL CHANGES WILL BE LOST!' , function (answer) {
                if (!answer) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // User agrees so swicth tabs so take him to the one he requested.
                    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", ui.newTab.index());
                }
            });
        }           
    }   
})
</script>
```

Comment: You mean `$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", ui.newTab.index());` is not working? Could you create a [mcve] ..?

Comment: I actually realised that the problem is that the beforeChange event was looping

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26807729/2333214 and do upvote if it helps ;)

Comment: Exactly the solution I used